# How to prove this claim about this function?

Tags: calculus

I thnk first I need to show the that the function is monotonic.
Or maybe use it for the proof of this claim :

for all $$c > 0
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaam4yaiabg6
% da+iaaygW7caaIWaaaaa!3A2A!
$$ there's exists a solution for the equation $$f(x) = c
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaamOzaiaacI
% cacaWG4bGaaiykaiabg2da9iaacogaaaa!3B24!
$$

for :

$$f(x) = \left( {\begin{array}{*{20}{c}}{\frac{{{e^x} - 1}}{x}}&{x \ne 0}\\1&{x = 0}\end{array}} \right)
% MathType!MTEF!2!1!+-
% feaagKart1ev2aaatCvAUfeBSjuyZL2yd9gzLbvyNv2CaerbuLwBLn
% hiov2DGi1BTfMBaeXatLxBI9gBaerbd9wDYLwzYbItLDharqqtubsr
% 4rNCHbGeaGqiVu0Je9sqqrpepC0xbbL8F4rqqrFfpeea0xe9Lq-Jc9
% vqaqpepm0xbba9pwe9Q8fs0-yqaqpepae9pg0FirpepeKkFr0xfr-x
% fr-xb9adbaqaaeGaciGaaiaabeqaamaabaabaaGcbaGaamOzaiaacI
% cacaWG4bGaaiykaiabg2da9maabmaabaqbaeqabiGaaaqaamaalaaa
% baGaamyzamaaCaaaleqabaGaamiEaaaakiabgkHiTiaaigdaaeaaca
% WG4baaaaqaaiaadIhacqGHGjsUcaaIWaaabaGaaGymaaqaaiaadIha
% cqGH9aqpcaaIWaaaaaGaayjkaiaawMcaaaaa!479F!
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Show that the function is continuous everywhere, calculate the limit as $x$ goes to infinity and minus infinity, and then apply the Intermediate Value Theorem.

Answer (score 0):

We have, for $x \neq 0$: $$f(x) = \frac{e^x - 1}{x}$$ and $$f'(x) = \frac{e^x(x-1) +1}{x^2}$$

Since $f'(x) > 0$ then our function is increasing. To complete this proof, find the limit of $f(x)$ as $x \to -\infty$ and show that $f(x) = c$ will always have a solution.

If $x=0$, take $c=1$ and we are done.